# Java regex with multiple possible endings

Tags: java, regex

I need to write a regular expression that will match filenames that have a txt, htm, or html extension. I know that parens group characters together and that brackets allow one character from a set to be matched, so I tried combining these approaches, but it is not working. The string to be tested is in parts[1]. The .* should match any number of characters, and then \\. would be the dot, and then my attempt at combining brackets and parentheses follows.

```
if (!Pattern.matches(".*\\.[(txt)(htm)(html)]", parts[1])) {
    System.err.println("501 Not Implemented: " + parts[1] + "\n");
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should be:

```
if (!Pattern.matches(".*?\\.(txt|html?)", parts[1])) {
    System.err.println("501 Not Implemented: " + parts[1] + "\n");
}
```

- There is no grouping of text inside character class `[...]`
- `matches` method assumes anchors so `^` and `$` aren't needed.

Comment: Not sure why you have the two `?` in the pattern here.  It's redundant after `.*` and the OP never indicated that the file extension was optional.

Comment: `.*?` is called "lazy", not "greedy"!  Greedy would just be be `.*`.  Possessive would be `.*+`.

Comment: Yes sorry I mistyped, meant lazy but typed greedy :)

Comment: The last one, in 'html?' means that the 'l' is optional, so the regexp will match 'htm' or 'html'

Answer (score 2):

Just try with following regex:

```
".*\\.(txt|html?)$"
```